# Spring long polling ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, ajax, spring, concurrency, long-polling

Basically I have simple news app, now I want to have news list updated automatically for all users whenever someone adds or removes news, its kinda working but sometimes I get ConcurrentModificationException, I just need help in writing this method:

```
@GetMapping("/pollnews")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<ModelAndView> poll(Model model){
    DeferredResult<ModelAndView> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if(changeOccured){
                    changeOccured = false;
                    model.addAttribute("news", newsService.getAllNews());
                    result.setResult(new ModelAndView("partial"));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return result;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1456)
at com.newsapp.SpringNews.Service.NewsService.getAllNews(NewsService.java:25)
at com.newsapp.SpringNews.Controller.ViewController$1.run(ViewController.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: an you specify on which line the exception occurs?

Comment: It occurs in newsService class and getAllnews() method, but it doesn't matter since I think I wrote this poll() method wrong and problem is probably there...

Comment: can you add the stack trace to your question? as I don't see anything wrong with your method

Comment: Your exception is in `NewsService.getAllNews(NewsService.java:25)` however you are showing the method `poll()`. We need `getAllNews()`.

Comment: Additional issues not related to the problem but the posted code. Your `poll()` methods spawns a new Thread each time `/pollnews` is called and the `while(true)` will never exit. This will lead to out of memory over a certain period of time.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html `This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.` One thread is most likely modifying a collection while it is being iterated in some thread.

Comment: Thanks for answers I will try to rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

You use an arraylist to write data and get data concurently. ArrayList will fail on that. You need a List implementation that manage concurent access :

- Either you create your list like : List<..> list=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
- or you use real concurent list like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Anyway, pulling like that is really dangerous - you will hit network timeout,you will also kill you server with a lot of thread looping on the while true (on your code there is no wait!).

A much better approach would be to use ServerSideEvent (SSE) and event system.

Here a post on doing that with spring https://golb.hplar.ch/p/Server-Sent-Events-with-Spring

It manage a event system that make listener and producer totally decoupled.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I wanted to make it as simple as possible, also do you thinks its possible to refactor it to make it better and working?

Comment: Edited to add the concurent issue.